# Using Team Services to develop .net website on ubuntu

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

The company I'm working for is using Team Services on visualstudio.com for a C#.net project.  Following instructions found on-line I was able to properly setup the git repository and have Visual Studio Code recognize it.  What I've not been able to do is run the code on Linux.  I've had a really hard time finding useful information about setting up this kind of enviroment.  I was open to the possiblity of using Mono Develop instead but I have the same problem with it.

My question is how can I set up a project that has already been created and opened in Visual Studio or Mono so that I can work in a group through visualstudio.com (which is basically git).  I want to be certain I won't break anything when I sync and I want to figure out how to get the code to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Linux system, I suppose you are using Git source control. Setting up your development environment for using VS Team Services is quite easy with Non-Windows system. Follow these steps:

- Create an empty project in your Team Services account.
- It will provide some tips to clone this newly creating remote repository and add it to your local development environment.
- Follow those steps and make sure that it has added successfully. You can check for that by typing in the terminal as `git remote`.
- Make necessary progress in your project, commit it locally and push it to your Team Service account by typing `git push -u origin master` (If your remote repository is names **origin**. VS Code has a great UI tools for this.
- Repeat the process for your ongoing development project.

A best practice is to create a local Git branch on your system, checkout and make all of your project development there after it is done, merge it to the master and push it to the remote repository.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was being clear but rereading my question it was a little vague.  I'll reword it to be more specific.